# Are there any problems that can only be solved recursively or only iteratively?

Tags: algorithm, loops, recursion

Is there any problem that can only be solved in recursion or iteration. If not, can all algorithms be represented in either form having the same complexity?

**PS:** I'm talking about the theoretical complexity(O, theta and omega) and not about the time taken when implemented in real world systems.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Recursion and iteration are equally expressive: recursion can be replaced by iteration with an explicit stack, while iteration can be replaced with tail recursion.[1]

So no, every problem that can be solved iterative can be solved with recursion and vice-versa. If you do 1:1 conversion, Big-O notation stays the same. It can, however, still be better to use an iterative algorithm over a recursive because you can do different things.

1: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)#Recursion_versus_iteration